# older go versions on travis are killed in the middle of running tests

Tags: travis-ci

I made a new commit and my build for go 1.5.4 and go 1.6.3 started failing but go 1.7 was still working.
I then reverted this commit but it was still failing even though the previous commit was passing.
Then I rebuilt an old commit which was passing and still these older versions consistently fail.
https://travis-ci.org/gogo/protobuf/builds/171003019

While running tests these are failing with signal killed
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.5.4.linux.amd64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile: signal: killed
go build github.com/gogo/protobuf/test: /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.5.4.linux.amd64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile: signal: killed
go build github.com/gogo/protobuf/test/combos/both: /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.5.4.linux.amd64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile: signal: killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hit this issue on travis and adding the option `sudo: required` seems to fix this. Possibly due to more memory available in the sudo-enabled env https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/precise/

Comment: Perfect.  That seemed to work :)  Thank you very much.